# Java print multiple copies but only one ends up at the printer

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am trying to print multiple copies of a pdf document. After googling around a bit I found that I have to put a Copies in a PrintRequestAttributeSet. But after doing this only 1 copy is printed instead of the amount I provided.

During debugging I can see that the print object changes its copies variable from 0 to 2, so I would assume I do everything correctly. I've also been playing around a bit with the collation and multipledocumenthandling variables, but the end result stays the same.

Does anyone know how I can get it to print the correct number of copies?

My code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MultipleDocumentHandling;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.SheetCollate;

public class PrintTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(
                        "<Insert pdf file here>"));

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

        Copies copies = new Copies(2);

        SheetCollate collate = SheetCollate.COLLATED;

        MultipleDocumentHandling handling = MultipleDocumentHandling.SEPARATE_DOCUMENTS_COLLATED_COPIES;

        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        pras.add(copies);
        pras.add(collate);
        pras.add(handling);

        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();

        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

        printJob.print(doc, pras);
    }
}
```

---

So I've been playing around a bit more. I've added a few sysout statements using which I found out you have something called Fidelity which can be used to force it to reject the print job if it cannot be printed exactly as specified. But there are some issues with this. After adding the fidelity setting to it I end up with the following output:

```
[class javax.print.attribute.standard.JobName, class javax.print.attribute.standard.RequestingUserName, class javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies, class javax.print.attribute.standard.Destination, class javax.print.attribute.standard.OrientationRequested, class javax.print.attribute.standard.PageRanges, class javax.print.attribute.standard.Media, class javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaPrintableArea, class javax.print.attribute.standard.Fidelity, class javax.print.attribute.standard.SheetCollate, class sun.print.SunAlternateMedia, class javax.print.attribute.standard.Chromaticity, class javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides, class javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution]
[]
Exception in thread "main" sun.print.PrintJobAttributeException: unsupported attribute: collated
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.getAttributeValues(Win32PrintJob.java:667)
    at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Win32PrintJob.java:332)
    at net.pearlchain.print.distribute.jasper.PrintTest.main(PrintTest.java:52)
```

The unsupported attribute is different with each execution but always one of the attributes I have set. I have tried running it using java 6 and java 7 and the only difference I get is the line on which the exception is thrown. On java 6 it is on line 667 and on java 7 it is line 685. Looking at the code found at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/print/Win32PrintJob.java) I can see the exception being thrown but the actual reason is unclear.

---

Ok, I've found out why this happens, the flavor I've selected does not support multiple copies. Setting it to pdf leads me to getting a flavornotsupported exception because I have no printers installed which support printing from a pdf source.

---

It's been a long time and I forgot to post my solution here for future visitors.

I solved this by adding a 3rd party pdf library (Apache PDFBox) which provided me with an inputstream which I could send to the printer with all the settings I required.

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

I no longer have access to the code but this could be useful for future visitors. :)

Comment: Try to have a look at (this stackoverflow topic)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034491/javax-print-attribute-printrequestattributeset-options-ignored-by-printer], if you didn't.